# How to evaluate Poisson Bracket?

Tags: physics, education

I'am new in Mathematica so please don't yell at me.

I want to define Poisson Bracket in Mathematica 9 and evaluate it for two functions,but it didn't worked. Could you help me please?

```
F1[r_, phi_] := 
r^2*p^2[phi]*Cos[2*phi] - r^3*p[phi]*p[r]*Sin[2*phi] + 
r^-1*Sin[phi]*Sin[2*phi]
F2[r_, phi_] := 
r^2*p^2[phi]*Cos[2*phi] + r^3*p[phi]*p[r]*Sin[2*phi] - 
 r^-1*Sin[phi]*Sin[2*phi]

PoissonBracket[r_, phi_] := (D[F1, r]*D[F2, phi] - D[F1, phi]*D[F2, r])
```

Comment: You just forgot to add the function arguments in the definition of `PoissionBracket`. Replace `F1` by `F1[r, phi]` etc.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the notation `p^2[phi]`?  If you mean the square of `p[phi]`, Mathematica requires you enter it as `p[phi]^2`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!